# Converting struct c ++ programs to c language

Tags: c++, c, struct

I'm working on a problem on the e-Olymp.

I have solved the problem using c ++. Here is a program that I have created:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int m, MOD = 1000003;

struct Math //Deklaraasi struct dengan MOD
{
    long pow_mod(long a, long p)
    {
        if (a >= m) a %= MOD;
        if (a == 0) return 0;
        if (p == 0) return 1;
        long t = pow_mod(a, p / 2);
        if (p & 1) return a * t % MOD * t % MOD;
        return t*t % MOD;
    }
    long inverse(long a) { return pow_mod(a, MOD - 2); }
    long C_MOD(long n, long k)
    {
        long ans = 1;
        if (k > n / 2) k = n - k;
        for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++)
        {
            ans *= n - k + i;
            ans %= MOD;
            ans *= inverse(i);
            ans %= MOD;
        }
        return ans;
    }
} math;

struct BST      //Struct untuk BST
{
    struct node {
        int val, sz, F;
        node *ch[2];
    } *root;
    void Del(node* T)
    {
        if (!T) return;
        Del(T->ch[0]);
        Del(T->ch[1]);
        delete T;
    }
    void reset()    //Fungsi untuk mereset
    {
        Del(root);
        root = nullptr;
    }
    int getsz(node *T) { return T ? T->sz : 0; }
    void insert(int v, node* &T)
    {
        if (!T)
        {
            T = new node();
            T->val = v;
            T->sz = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            insert(v, T->ch[v > T->val]);
            T->sz = getsz(T->ch[0]) + getsz(T->ch[1]) + 1;
        }
    }
    int f(node* T)
    {
        if (!T) return 1;
        if (T->F) return T->F;
        return T->F = (long)f(T->ch[0]) * f(T->ch[1]) % MOD \
            * math.C_MOD(getsz(T->ch[0]) + getsz(T->ch[1]), getsz(T->ch[0])) % MOD;
    }
} bst;

int main()
{
    int T, n, A[1010];
    scanf("%d", &T);
    for (int kase = 1; kase <= T; kase++)   //Perulangan sebanyak input pengguna atau T
    {
        scanf("%d%d", &n, &m);
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) scanf("%d", &A[i]);
        //membuat BST
        bst.reset();
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) bst.insert(A[i], bst.root);
        int ans = bst.f(bst.root) * math.C_MOD(m, n) % MOD;
        printf("%d\n", ans);
    }
}
```

Next I want to try to convert the program into c language, to solve the problem. But I am still a beginner in the c language and have experienced some problems in applying structures where the c struct language cannot be made like in c ++.

How do I solve the problem or convert my c ++ program to c using the appropriate struct in c language?

Thank you.

Comment: what did you try? How did it fail? Where are you stuck? Congrats for realizing that C is not C++, but still as a first trial I would simply ask a C compiler to compile it and see what happens. Did you do that already?

Comment: There is no such thing as member functions in `C`.  This requires a rewrite, not just a mere "translation" or "conversion".  Also, online competition coding sites are *not* the way to actually learn another computer language.  Those sites expect you to use the computer language you already know, and know it well enough to not have to ask questions on how to use that language.

Comment: In c language, There can be  no functions in struct type. You can write the inner struct functions as ordinary functions, using the struct instance as the parameter.

Comment: regarding the C++ posted code.  It seems that the `struct` objects should be `class` objects.  The functions in the `struct` examples should be either `public` or `private`  There should be an access function for each of the variables within the `struct` objects. I don't see the constructor nor destructor nor copy functions within the `struct` objects, so they will be generated with the default constructor & destructor & copy functions.  Probably not what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To translate your C++ code to C, you mainly need to change the member functions to regular functions, which take the struct they would act on as an argument instead.
On example would be changing

```c
void reset()
```

to

```c
void reset(BST* bst)
```

and inside that function `root` by `bst->root`
of course you can use references instead of pointers to avoid null-checking.
hence your `Math` doesn't contain any state anyway, you could just remove it and use the function as regular functions (and also remove the `math.` at the calls).

Consider also renaming the functions to group your logical groups, e.g. `bst_reset(BST* bst)` as new name.

Further, you need to change some further stuff, which is unkown to C.
Those are:

- change `nullptr` to `NULL` (same usage)
- replace `#include <iostream>` by `#include <stdio.h>` (containing scanf and printf)
- remove `using namespace std;` without replacement (there are no namespaces in C)
- replace `new node()` by `(node*) malloc(sizeof(node))` (note that the values contained in the struct are always undefined, because there is nothing like a constructor) and `delete T` by `free(T)`
- to use `malloc` and `free`, you also need to include `#include <stdlib.h>`

your nested `struct node` probably also needs to be moved out of the `struct BST`